# How to call a function inside stream of hash map object , & accumulate sum based on output of method called inside stream

Tags: java-8

```
double finalPrice = 0;


        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> eachBasketItemEntry:itemsInBasket.entrySet()){
            Integer itemId = eachBasketItemEntry.getKey();
            if(itemPricingRuleMap.containsKey(itemId)){
                //calculate pricing based on pricing rule for that item code
                finalPrice+=calculateItemPrice(itemId,eachBasketItemEntry.getValue(),itemPricingRuleMap);
            }
            else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No pricing rule regsitered for the item with item id"+itemId);
            }
        }
        return finalPrice;
```

```
 private double calculateItemPrice(Integer itemId, Integer itemsCount,Map<Integer, PricingRule> itemPricingRuleMap) {
        PricingRule pricingRule = itemPricingRuleMap.get(itemId);
        return pricingRule.calculatePrice(itemsCount);
    }
```

How to convert this into java8 streams?

```
        double a1 = itemsInBasket.entrySet().stream().forEach(eachBasketItemEntry->{
            double finalPrice = 0;
            Integer itemId = eachBasketItemEntry.getKey();
            finalPrice+= calculateItemPrice(itemId,eachBasketItemEntry.getValue(),itemPricingRuleMap);
        })
```

Tried doing this but Im unsure how to proceed from here..

Can any one help.

Im new to java 8 streams

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add complete program with data ?

Comment: You convert to Stream by not using `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-map-java-examples/) to map your result calculated from `calculateItemPrice` method and then use [`reduce()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-reduce-java-examples/) operation to get required result.

**Wrote a sample example for explanation**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> itemsInBasket = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();//Creating HashMap
        itemsInBasket.put(1, 5);  //Put elements in Map
        itemsInBasket.put(2, 6);
        itemsInBasket.put(3, 7);
        itemsInBasket.put(4, 8);

        int a1 = itemsInBasket
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> (e.getKey() + e.getValue()))
                .reduce(Integer::sum).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
        System.out.println(a1);


    }

}
```

**For your case : below code can help**

```
  double a1 =  itemsInBasket
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e->calculateItemPrice(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), itemPricingRuleMap))
                .reduce(Double::sum).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

**EDIT : As @Holger Suggested it can be rewritten as**

```
  double a1 =  itemsInBasket
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .mapToDouble(e->calculateItemPrice(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), itemPricingRuleMap))
                .sum().orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
```

Let me know in comments further if you face further issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Or `mapToDouble(…).sum()`.

Answer (score 3):

**You can refer the below sample code whenever some one wants to iterate over the collection and wants to get the reduced single value output.**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String,Integer> employeeSalaryMap = new HashMap<>();

        employeeSalaryMap.put("emp1",10000);
        employeeSalaryMap.put("emp2",20000);
        employeeSalaryMap.put("emp3",30000);
        employeeSalaryMap.put("emp4",40000);
        employeeSalaryMap.put("emp5",50000);

        int totalSalaryOfAllEmployees1 = employeeSalaryMap.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
        
        int totalSalaryOfAllEmployees2 = employeeSalaryMap.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .reduce(Integer::sum).orElseThrow(Exception::new);

        System.out.println("totalSalaryOfAllEmployees1:: " + totalSalaryOfAllEmployees1);
        System.out.println("totalSalaryOfAllEmployees2:: " + totalSalaryOfAllEmployees2);

    }
}

**Output**
totalSalaryOfAllEmployees1:: 150000
totalSalaryOfAllEmployees2:: 150000
```

Both the operations will give you the same result.
Recommended to use: mapToInt/mapToDouble based on the requirements.

Thanks